# How to register an application with the Microsoft identity platform via Terraform code

Tags: azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Register an application with the Microsoft identity platform can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app)

Each time when I redeploy the application, the registration will be deleted from the identity platform, and I don't want to do doing the registration again by click around in the portal.

Can I doing this via Terraform azure provider code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [terraform Azure Active Directory provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs) to manage it. You could refer to samples in [this blog](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/automate-azure-ad-app-registration-using-terraform/) for more details.

For example, you may want to registry a basic application and associated it with a service principal then assign a contributor role to it.

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Provider
provider "azuread" {}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name               = "example"

}

# Create a service principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id = azuread_application.example.application_id
}

# Assign a Contributor role
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
}
```